# Running ssh from ruby on rails app in apache server is not working but it works with the WEBrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, apache2, webrick

I have configured the Ruby On Rails Project on the `Apache` with the `passenger` but when I am doing the `ssh` using the application then its not working and gives this error in the apache log.

`Could not create directory '/var/www/.ssh'.`

`Host key verification failed.`

But when I run the same project on the `WEBrick` server then it works fine.

I am running the command in following way.

`system("ssh machine command")`

Comment: Yeah, @swati has it right.  Probably issues with apache running as a different user, such as apache or root.

Comment: @MarlinPierce how can I check the apache is running as which user...any idea?

Comment: Thanks...@MarlinPierce I can see the difference in the user. when I check the user with apache it says `www-data` and when I so the same opetaion with the Webrick server then it says `root`....But how can I achieve the running the `ssh` command in the apache..any solution...?

Comment: You are going to have to play around and see what the errors are.  ~swati gave you the link for adding the ssh host key, which is your current error.  There could be file permission issues and environment variable issues, but each is its own question, and if you use search engines, you can find specific answers.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Check it out : http://blog.servergrove.com/2010/08/02/ssh-strange-error-host-key-verification-failed/

Comment: In my case the remote server's keys are already added to the known_host file.
And more important that ssh is working with the webrick server and not with the apache

Comment: Webrick is probably running as you, Apache is running as a different user (www-data, usually), as such it'll have a different known_hosts file

Answer (score 0):

Host Key Verification Failure happens because you've already attempted to connect to a host @ the same address, but the key that identifies the SSH server does not match the one that you connected to previously.

#### Make sure you are connecting to the server you think you are

If you are absolutely certain you are connecting to the same server then you can do one of the following:

- Remove the offending key from `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and try again
- Edit your ssh config ( /etc/ssh/ssh_config ) and disable host-key checking: `StrictHostKeyChecking no`